# Cannot load swf from another domain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, load, vk

I'm successfully loading swf from another domain, but when i addChild loaded content, it doesn't appear on the stage.
My firebug shows that swf loaded with status (304 Not Modified), means no problem.

Why i cannot see loaded swf content on the stage?

Thank you

Comment: Download latest [debug version of flash player from here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html#fp10). When you run the SWF after installing the debug player (and restarting the browser), you'll see that there is an exception being thrown. Post the error number and message, if it's not clear for you. The issue might be that you don't have permission (thru proper crossdomain.xml files) to load the file.

Comment: I get no error. I successfully open external swf file in debugger.
I'm using MultiImageLoader class

I realized that it stops working when loaded swf file tries to load other external swfs.

I hope somebody faced with this problem before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem. 
I wanna share it to you, because anyone can face with such a problem. This problem doesn't cause any error, so it's hard to find it.

We need just add loaderContext as second parameter in **load** method. Before assigning it there we must declare it in this way: 
`var loader_context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();`
`if (Security.sandboxType!='localTrusted') loader_context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;`
`loader_context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;`

`loader.load(url, loader_context);`

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

maybe its a crossdomain problem.
do you have a crossdomain.xml file on the external server?

[example xml](http://curtismorley.com/2007/09/01/flash-flex-tutorial-how-to-create-a-crossdomainxml-file/)

Comment: Yes i have crossdomain.xml file in server where i store external swfs. My loader class loads them, but complete event listener doesn't fire. Any suggessions, is there best multi image/swf loader classes in AS3?

Comment: I have checked the sandboxtype for files, it's is Security.sandboxType: remote. Is it okey?

Comment: Well my friend , you can use this link for loading multi image/swfs files 
http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/
http://www.stimuli.com.br/trane/2007/nov/25/loading-reloaded/